# Code Igniter does not recognize my base-url when I call a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, controllers

My app recognizes main page index.php (that calls a controller which name is Home and shows this Home page, as expected).

Although when I call a topic in the menu (which is also a controller), it fails with this error:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

http://alfa.teste:80/estrutura  where

http://alfa.teste/ is the base url and 'estrutura' is the controller.

Please, any help? Thank you so much!

Comment: have you tried http://alfa.teste:80/index.php/estrutura ? if it works then you need htaccess file

Comment: Hi danny, Thank you so much. It works when I tried alfa.teste:80/index.php/estrutura.

Comment: I´ve already defined base url in config.php and I´ve also defined an index method. My .htaccess may be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

in config.php file put this small code bellow base_url array

> $config['base_url'] = ' ';

```
//try to catch the base url in case of undefined base url 
if (!$config['base_url']) {

    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    $domain = preg_replace('/index.php.*/', '', $domain);
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $config['base_url'] = 'https://' . $domain;
    } else {
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $domain;
    }
}
```

and in autoload.php file you need to add url in helper array like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Your code will work fine if you call base url function

> base_url();

If this still not works for you then you need to create an .htaccess file in root folder of the project. write the following code in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I hope any of the above solution will work for you.

Comment: That is a spectacularly insecure way to determine and set `$config['base_url']`. Please search and read about the risks of using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. All the OP needs is `$config['base_url'] = 'http://alfa.teste/';`

Comment: Thank you Sankhnad and DFriend.  When I call http://alfa.teste:80/index.php/estrutura it works.   I had already defined base url in the config.php as http://alfa.teste.  I also using  .htaccess as yours above, but, unfortunately, it didn´t work and I am still getting a http error 404 not found

Comment: DFriend I´ve already used the base url in the config.php. I´ve also defined .htaccess but I am still getting this error. Looking forward to hearing from you anu suggestions, Thank you so much,